# Failed to connect to lvmetad

Tags: 16.10

After upgrading to ubuntu 16.10 I get this warning in my boot.log file

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 1180656/30154752 files, 16007858/120604672 blocks
```

Seems to be an issue that is related to disk encryption. The system startup properly and I do not see any bad behaviour, however do anybody have an idea how to fix

Answer (score 2):

I get the same warning on Ubuntu 16.10 with encrypted LVM. I have not found a solution but, for what it's worth, it appears related to the Debian bug reported on 16 Nov 2016.

My server works fine so I'm hoping it's a minor bug that will be fixed in upcoming Ubuntu releases.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844487

> Dear Maintainer,
>
> I am using Debian Scratch with encrypted root partition. The last
>   kernel version where it worked was 4.6.0. For kernels 4.7.0 and 4.8.0
>   it prints on the boot repeatedly and forever following messages:
>
> WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device
>   scanning.   Volume group "martin-vg" not found   Cannot process volume
>   group martin-vg
>
> In 4.6.0 these messages are shown too, but only twice and then it
>   prompts for a password:
>
> Please unlock disk sda5_crypt: